Count all and count all that are not read, Can I do this with one query?
I have a table where are all sick users. But I have also a column named read. this is to show the admin new users that he does not read it yet.
Now I have a dashboard and want to show all ill users + all unread users.
Can I do this with one query or should I do this with transaction and two queries ?
current I have this:
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users_ill
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users_ill WHERE read = false


Look into conditional aggregation or the filter clause.

SELECT COUNT(*) AS all_sicks, COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE read = false) AS unread_sicks FROM users_ill

@JonasMetzler I want to convert it with INT but this not works

SELECT COUNT()::int AS all_sicks, COUNT()::int FILTER(WHERE read = false) AS unread_sicks FROM users_ill

No idea what you try to do there. If you need further assistance, you should create another question.

You can did it using conditional agregation:
 SELECT 
    COUNT(id) AS total_ill_users,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN read = false THEN 1 END) AS unread_users
FROM 
    users_ill;

I strongly advise you to learn more about this concept
